# ASP.NET Core LinkedIn Authentication Not Getting Data

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, linkedin-api

I'm implementing LinkedIn authentication in my ASP.NET Core app but for some reason I'm not getting any data from LinkedIn. Where am I making a mistake?

In ConfigureServices of Startup.cs, I have the following:

```
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

In Configure of Startup.cs, I have the following code:

```
app.AuthenticationForMyApp(
                Configuration["linkedInClientId"],
                Configuration["linkedInClientSecret"],
                Configuration["linkedInCallback"]);
```

My code looks like this in AuthenticationForMyApp class:

```
public static void AuthenticationForMyApp(this IApplicationBuilder app, string linkedInClientId, string linkedInSecret, string linkedInCallback)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/unauthorized"),
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true
            });

            app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "LinkedIn",
                ClientId = linkedInClientId,
                ClientSecret = linkedInSecret,
                CallbackPath = linkedInCallback,
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
                TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)",
                Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" },
                Events = new OAuthEvents()
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallback,
                    OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
                }
            });

        }
        private static Task OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallback(OAuthCreatingTicketContext ctx)
        {
            var token = ctx.AccessToken;

            // *** Here ctx.User has no data about the user!!!
            var firstName = ctx.User["first_name"];
            var lastName = ctx.User["last_name"];
            var gender = ctx.User["gender"];
            var email = ctx.User["email"];
            var identity = ctx.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            if (firstName != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, firstName.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"));
            }
            if (lastName != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, lastName.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"));
            }
            if (email != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email, email.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"));
            }
            if (gender != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, gender.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"));
            }

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("linkedin.token", token));

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        private static Task OnTicketReceivedCallback(TicketReceivedContext ctx)
        {
            var identity = ctx.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity == null)
            {
                ctx.ReturnUri = "/unauthorized";
            }
            else
            {
                if (ctx.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("returnUrl"))
                {
                    ctx.ReturnUri += "?returnUrl=" + ctx.Properties.Items["returnUrl"];
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
```

Comment: There's already a package for LinkedIn: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationExtensions.cs

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't want to bloat my app with any unnecessary code/packages/libraries. I really should be able to make this code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the OAuth2 generic middleware as-is, `OAuthCreatingTicketContext.User` is never pre-populated because it's up to you to send the "userinfo" request to retrieve the user profile from the remote OAuth2 provider.

Update `OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallback` to send an HTTP request to LinkedIn's userinfo endpoint and retrieve the JSON response you need or switch to the [aspnet-contrib LinkedIn middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn/) that will do that for you, as suggested by [@Tratcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588374/tratcher).